# Finding the probability of running a system with joint probability of compound events

Tags: probability

I have a system composed of 5 components ($X_{i}$), each of which works with probability $p_{i}$ independently of each other (if it works $X_{i}$ = 1, otherwise 0) and I know that as a whole the system works if components 1 and 2 work either or if 3 and 4 work or if 1 , 3 and 5 work.
I want to find the probability that the system will work.

Defining:
$$A = \{ x_{1}=1,x_{2}=1 \} \qquad B = \{ x_{3}=1,x_{4}=1 \} \qquad C = \{ x_{1}=1,x_{3}=1,x_{5}=1 \}$$

$$P(A) = p_{1} * p_{2} \qquad P(B) = p_{3} * p_{4} \qquad P(C) = p_{1} * p_{3} * p_{5}$$
 $$P(AB) = p_{1} * p_{2} * p_{3} * p_{4}  \qquad P(AC) = p_{1} * p_{2} *  p_{1} * p_{3} * p_{5}\qquad P(BC) = p_{3} * p_{4}* p_{1} * p_{3} * p_{5}$$
 $$ P(ABC) = p_{1} * p_{2} * p_{3} * p_{4} * p_{1} * p_{3} * p_{5}$$

The probability that the system will work is:
$$P(A \cup B \cup C)  = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(AB) -P(AC) - P(BC) + P(ABC) = $$
 $$ = p_{1} * p_{2} + p_{3} * p_{4} + p_{1} * p_{3} * p_{5} - p_{1} * p_{2} * p_{3} * p_{4} -p_{1} * p_{2} *  p_{1} * p_{3} * p_{5} $$
 $$- p_{3} * p_{4}* p_{1} * p_{3} * p_{5} + p_{1} * p_{2} * p_{3} * p_{4} * p_{1} * p_{3} * p_{5} $$

My reasoning is correct or I have to calculate all joint events such as intersections of the components, for example: $ P(AC) $ as $ P(A \cap C) = p_{1} $ ?

I think the correct option is the first as the odds are independent. Am I wrong or is the solution right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are confused about something like this, it is often useful to work up a simple test case by hand to clarify your thinking. In this case, you could just set all the probabilities to $0.5$ and see what happens. In this case, all combinations of working and non-working components are equally likely. There are $2^5 = 32$ different combinations, so the probability of a given event is simply the number of combinations that satisfy the event divided by $32$.

$AC$ requires $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1, x_3 =1, x_5 = 1$, so there are only two combinations that satisfy it: when $x_4 = 0$ and when $x_4 = 1$. Thus its probability is $\dfrac 2{32} = \dfrac 1{16}$.

Which of your two proffered calculations for $P(AC)$ matches this when all the $p_i$ are $1/2$?

Comment: Indeed reasoning in this way calculate the probability as component intersections would not make sense, but in the first case it would result $P(AC) = (\frac{1}{2})^{5} = \frac{1}{32}$ if I follow the formula accurately (because $p_{1}$ is multiplied twice).
Do I have to consider $p_{1}$ only once in this case? If so, you could explain the reasoning to understand it and transform it into formulas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't look closely enough at your formula before to see that you had included $p_1$ twice. $A$ and $C$ are not independent events, so in general, $P(AC) \ne P(A)P(C)$. You need to think about what you are doing here. If $A$ holds, then $X_1$ has occurred, so now $C$ only depends on whether $X_3$ and $X_5$ have also occurred. $AC = X_1X_2X_3X_5$ and since the $X_i$ are independent, $$P(AC) = P(X_1X_2X_3X_5) = P(X_1)P(X_2)P(X_3)P(X_5) = p_1\cdot p_2\cdot p_3\cdot p_5$$